# Is it necessary to define ng-model every time?

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs /1.4./angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<form ng-app="" name="myForm">
Email:
<input type="email" name="myAddress" ng-model="text">
<span ng-show="myForm.myAddress.$error.email">Not a valid e-mail address</span>
</form>

<p>Enter your e-mail address in the input field. AngularJS will display an errormessage if the address is not an e-mail.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Above code i have learnt form w3school
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_model_validate

In above code email entered is taken by ng-show="myForm.myAddress.$error.email" syntax

ng-model="text" is never used so if I remove that from code or set to blank like this ng-model=" " it won't work

What is concept behind this?

What is exactly use of ng-model in above code?

Comment: ng-model attribute is the actor responsible to bind validations, like required, masks, type="email", etc. You can use and put a unused variable, like your example. Angular will runs without ng-model, but the validations don't will occur

Answer (score 0):

Basically ng-model used for bind the input box value and send to js where your angular controller defined, You can access you ng-model="name" value in your controller like this var myName = $scope.name and in HTML simply {{name}} If you do not want input box value you can skip and remove ng-model from Input box

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs /1.4./angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<form ng-app="" name="myForm">
Email:
<input type="email" name="myAddress" ng-model="text">
<span ng-show="myForm.myAddress.$error.email">Not a valid e-mail address</span>
</form>

<p>Enter your e-mail address in the input field. AngularJS will display an errormessage if the address is not an e-mail.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

For better expiation read this  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: I understand ng-model binds html value and it is used by its model name in expression {{ }} . But here value is fetched by myForm.myAddress. If I change above ng-model = "Text" to ng-model = "anyname" it still works

Comment: no problem Yes you can btw If you change ng-model = "Text" to ng-model = "anyname" then you have to change {{Text}} to {{anyname}} in html and in js $scope.Text to $scope.anyname

Answer (score 0):

If you are never going to use a particular model, you don't need to write `ng-model` attribute itself. But if you are writing `ng-model`, then you have to declare proper model name, like `ng-model="text"` (or any other valid model name).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
  angular.module('emailExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.email = {
        text: 'me@example.com'
      };
    }]);
</script>
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <label>Email:
      <input type="email" name="input" ng-model="email.text" required>
    </label>
    <div role="alert">
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
        Required!</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.email">
        Not valid email!</span>
    </div>
    <tt>text = {{email.text}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$error.email = {{!!myForm.$error.email}}</tt><br/>
  </form>
```

Hello ,

```
ng-model="text" // you can give whatever you like ex: 
ng-model="mytext" this is useful while rendering with $scope
```

coming to 
`ng-show="myForm.myAddress.$error.email`" which is the validation 
for the email 
where myForm is your declared form name
myaddress is your input name
and $error.email is validation of angular js

you can look into the bellow detailed code for your better understanding

```
<script>
  angular.module('emailExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.email = {
        text: 'me@example.com'
      };
    }]);
</script>
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <label>Email:
      <input type="email" name="input" ng-model="email.text" required>
    </label>
    <div role="alert">
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
        Required!</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.email">
        Not valid email!</span>
    </div>
    <tt>text = {{email.text}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$error.email = {{!!myForm.$error.email}}</tt><br/>
  </form>
```

Output

```
Email:  
Required! 
text = 
myForm.input.$valid = false
myForm.input.$error = {"required":true}
myForm.$valid = false
myForm.$error.required = true
myForm.$error.email = false
```

Run it if you want
Refer this link for more details 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D